# Workaround for breezejs not supporting cascade delete?

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, cascade, cascading-deletes

It caused me a big headache until I found out that breezejs doesn't support cascade delete yet from this [link](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3901287-client-side-cascade-delete). I tried to workaround this limitation by adding a cascade delete constraint to database table directly. However, it doesn't seem working for breeze either (it works if I manually delete the parent row). From my observation, when breeze deletes a parent row, it sets the foreign key of the child to null. Any idea?

By the way, to avoid breeze throw exception on delete, I had to make the foreign key nullable. I also have to turn off cascade delete on entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few months old, but I stumbled upon this question too many times while searching for solution so it might help someone. Here is a workaround I managed to pull off (not thoroughly tested, but it works for initial few tests).

Assume I have a parent class `Parent` and a child class `Child`. Child can only exist if Parent exists.

In Context class (the one where you put `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` function) you write following:

```
public override int SaveChanges(){
  foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where((e => (e.State == (EntityState)Breeze.WebApi.EntityState.Deleted))))
    {
      if (entry.EntityType.GetType() == typeof(Parent)){
        var entity = entry.Entity as Parent;
        var allChildren = Children.Where(p => p.ParentId == entity.Id);
        foreach (var singleChild in allChildren){
          Children.Remove(singleChild);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The downside is - you need to write this for every single delete where Cascade would usually occur. Also, keep in mind if you put class `Toy` having a parent class `Child`, you would have to manually address that one too.

Comment: I tried your code, strangely, my override SaveChanges doesn't get hit at all. Then, I tried similar code in BeforeSaveEntity() of my repository and I still get the error like `Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'xxx' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. ... Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.`. It doesn't seem matter if I turn on/off cascade on delete.

Comment: Actually, what is your Children? I guess it must be entity.Children, right?